# strange mysql and php behavior

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this is a strange question
but i use a query to get certain value from database based on name
the name exist in database and if i add a new product it grabs the name
but on old products it does not

here is my db structure
[Vaporama.be SQL pdf](http://vaporama.be/vapor.pdf)

site for demo
http://vaporama.be

pphp Code

```
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM category WHERE cat = 'product' ORDER BY name ASC");
    $stmt->execute();
    $category = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($category as $cat) {
        $naam = $cat['name'];
        //subcats query en count
        $stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat = :name GROUP BY (merk) ORDER BY name ASC");
        $stmt2->execute(array(':name' => $naam));
        $count = $stmt2->rowcount();
        //echo cats
        echo "
                <li class='dropdown'>
                    <a class='dropdown-toggle' href='#'>
                        {$naam} ({$count})
                    </a>
            ";
        $subcat = $stmt2->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //echo subcats
        echo "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>";
        foreach($subcat as $sub) {
            $stmt3 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM merken WHERE name = :merk ORDER BY name ASC");
            $stmt3->execute(array(':merk' => $sub['merk']));
            $merk = $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            echo "
                    <li><a href='//{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}/merk?merk={$merk[id]}'>{$sub[merk]}</a></li>
                ";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo '<h2><font color=red>';
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
    die ('</h2></font> ');
}
```

so basicly it should show it and grab the id
now that it exactly what it NOT does

but if i add a new product , then it does work
even more fun , my code says to GROUP so all names should be unic
in my dropdown i see now 2 time JOYETECH where the first one does not contain a id and the second contains my id ( 33 )

so why does it not GROUP the result and doesnt find it back like it need to be ?
here is the db of the WORKING item ( id 33 ) , the above is the NON working item

> id | name | merk
>   64 | test | JOYETECH

i do not see any difference ?
Greets from PowerChaos

and here is the screenshot how it looks now
[image: no id and double name]

Comment: Group means to group the lines together by that column, so you are not getting the individual rows.

Comment: Your table descriptions are incomplete. `SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat = :name GROUP BY (merk) ORDER BY name ASC` and I don't see a **cat** column in your products table description. Also I would like to seee clearly the results you get and that are wrong, and the expected results. Please edit  your answer to add this information. Also although I more or less understand the idea behind your <ul> lists, it would be nice to present the desired finished results someway because your whole approach probably needs to be changed to be optimal.